# vba range.find method stops on random cells

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, find

I wrote this quick For Loop as part of my macro to find cells in utwbk, based on a list of values in dewbk. The loop seems to go fine for a few cells and then crashes. The problem is, it crashes for different values each time but the values DO exist in utwbk. Here is my code:

```
Dim utpath As String
Dim utwbk As Workbook
Dim ogfund As String
Dim ogcell As Range
Dim newfund As String
Dim newcell As Range
Dim t As Long


For t = 2 To tempfundlastrow
If dewbk.Sheets("Macro").Cells(t, 1).Value <> "" Then
    Set ogcell = dewbk.Sheets("Macro").Cells(t, 1)
    ogfund = Trim(ogcell.Value)

    With utwbk.Sheets("Report").Range(Cells(1, 1), Range("AAA1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
    Set newcell = .Find(ogfund, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    End With

    newfund = newcell.Value

    newcell.Offset(2, 0).Value = ogcell.Offset(0, 8).Value
    newcell.Offset(3, 0).Value = ogcell.Offset(0, 9).Value
    newcell.Offset(4, 0).Value = ogcell.Offset(0, 11).Value
    newcell.Offset(6, 0).Value = ogcell.Offset(0, 10).Value
Else
    'nothing
End If
Next t
```

The code crashes with run-time error 91: 'Object variable of with block variable not set' on this line:

```
newfund = newcell.Value
```

In the previous line where I define newcell, ogfund has a value and I can find that value in utwbk so really not sure what's going on. I am assuming my syntax for the .Find is incorrect but I do not know how to rectify this. As usual, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe it didn't find `ogfund`. You need to test if `newcell is nothing`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the line

```
Set newcell = .Find(ogfund, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

Type this

```
If newcell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Not found"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

If you see the message box that means `.Find` couldn't find the search text and since it couldn't find, the `newcell.Value` will break the code as `newcell` is `Nothing`

BTW if you look for a word `BLAH` and in your cell you have `BLAH` with leading and trailing spaces then your `.Find` will not find the word because you are using `lookat:=xlWhole`. Maybe you want `lookat:=xlPart`

Comment: Thank Tim! I think I should hit the sack now :D

Answer (score 1):

It's a common mistake. In

```
utwbk.Sheets("Report").Range(Cells(1, 1), Range("AAA1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
```

`Cells(1, 1)` and `Range("AAA1")` refer to ranges in the currently active sheet

What you probably want is more like

```
With utwbk.Sheets("Report")
    With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Range("AAA1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
        Set newcell = .Find(ogfund, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    End With
End With
```

or just

```
With utwbk.Sheets("Report").UsedRange
    Set newcell = .Find(ogfund, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
End With
```